# VBA - Filling Combo Box with Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a problem with my ComboBox1, I am trying to make some hidden filters to make viewing lots of data easier and i want to select what i filter out via a combo box, where the input selection is part of this processed data.

Here is some code that i tried to write for populating the ComboBox but it comes up with an error saying that it is the wrong use of Method.

```
Sub ComboBox1_DropButton_Click()
Dim i As Range

With Sheets("Pipe 16")
Set i = .Range("G5:G" & .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "i"

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

this cannot be answered by the answers shown in [Dynamically set ListFillRange in Excel ComboBox using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200712/dynamically-set-listfillrange-in-excel-combobox-using-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set ListFillRange in Excel ComboBox using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200712/dynamically-set-listfillrange-in-excel-combobox-using-vba)

Comment: Have just tried what is suggested in here and it doesnt work @Dave

Comment: Try Me.ComboBox1.List = i.Value

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers just tried this and it didnt work

Comment: You realize you're trying to give it the string `i`? Not whatever was set to the variable in your `With` statement?  Try `Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=i"`.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: IT still has an error with the `Me.ComboBox1.......` where it is still saying - "invalid use of Me keyword"

Comment: Why are you putting the code in ComboBox1's DropButton_Click event? Rather put it in the form's Activate event.

Comment: I read up on another forum that it would work like that but evidently not

Comment: here is the old forum - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/410077-combo-box-dynamic-input-range.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListFillRange accept the range's address not the range itself.

```
Sub ComboBox1_DropButton_Click()

    Dim i As Range

    With Sheets("Pipe 16")
        Set i = .Range("G5:G" & .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = i.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox1.RowSource = ""
 ComboBox1.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

Comment: Posting code without any explanation isn't welcome here. Would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51320118/edit) your post ?