# Populating Combo Box

Tags: vba

While populating the Combo box, i am getting the error

> "Run time error 424 Object required".

Below is my code and i am trying to populate the list of countries(range name as countries) in the combo box.

```
Sub Country()
    Dim Count As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2")

    For Each Count In ws.Range("countries")
        With ComboBox1
            .AddItem Count.Value
        End With
    Next Count
End Sub
```

Please help me in resolving my errors.
Thanks in advance

Comment: On which line is the error?  Is this on a userform?

Comment: No ,It is not a useform. The error is coming on the line "With ComboBox1
            .AddItem Count.Value"

Comment: Where is the code?  You are just referencing ComboBox1, try referencing it on the sheet that it resides on. Like `With Sheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object` or `Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List = Sheets("countries").Range("A2:A10").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Also, from what your code looks like it is doing, why not use the `.ListFillRange` property to do this rather than a loop.

[Dynamically set ListFillRange in Excel ComboBox using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200712/dynamically-set-listfillrange-in-excel-combobox-using-vba)

Also where is the code? You are just referencing ComboBox1, try referencing it on the sheet that it resides on. Like

```
With Sheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.AddItem
```

or

```
Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List = Sheets("countries").Range("A2:A10").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your variable name from `Count` to something like `nCount`

Comment: nothing wrong with using count as a variable name (other than style). It's not a reserved keyword, just a property of many objects.