# How do I delete a specific item in a combobox list, when the user writes the name of the entry to be deleted in a dialogbox

Tags: excel, vba

So my problem is mostly explained in the title,I have a button that when pressed will ask "what do you want to delete?". Then the user writes what to delete and it is deleted from the list.

```
Sub DeleteShip()

Dim a As Variant
Dim b As String

a = InputBox("Vælg fartøj der skal slettes")
b = CStr(a)

If Sheet1.ShipList.Value = b Then
Sheet1.ShipList.RemoveItem (ShipList.ListIndex(b))
Else
MsgBox "Det skib findes ikke i listen, har du stavet det korrekt?"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: It all depends.... what kind of combobox and what's the source?  You've got a control on a form, or a form control on the sheet, or an activex control, or data validation combobox.  Then the list can be typed directly in as a source, or linked to a range on the spreadsheet... maybe some other way.  And as @Olly said....

Comment: Its an activex combobox, on a sheet. the box is linked to a cell.

I have tried list.removeitem (list.listindex) dones't work it says i need an object which is what i'm giving it.

Comment: Look here for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200712/dynamically-set-listfillrange-in-excel-combobox-using-vba/48804129. The listfillrange refering to a dynamic named range should be perfect for you. Just delete the row with the typed value in a sub.

Comment: @JvdV
That seems like overdoing it, can't i just somehow compare what the user writes in a dialogbox and compare it with the contents of my combobox, and if it exsists, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.  You may have to update the name of `ComboBox1`.

To find the name:
 - Select the combobox in Design Mode.
 - Click the *Format* ribbon.
 - In the *Arrange* section click the *Selection Pane*.
 - All shapes, their names & visibility will appear in a separate pane.

This will work if your using a range to fill your combobox:

```
Sub DeleteShp()

    Dim a As String
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim LookupRange As Range

    Set LookupRange = Range(Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange)

    a = Trim(InputBox("Vælg fartøj der skal slettes"))

    With LookupRange
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=a, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            rFound.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If you've populated your combobox using `AddItem`:

```
Sub InitialiseShp()
'Fills combobox with "Item A" to "Item F".
    Dim x As Long

    Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear

    For x = 65 To 70
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Item " & Chr(x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

You'll need to search the items to return the correct index number to remove:

```
Sub DeleteShp_2()

    Dim a As String
    Dim x As Long

    a = Trim(InputBox("Vælg fartøj der skal slettes"))

    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(x) = a Then
                .RemoveItem x
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but i get an error "Method "range" of object "_Global" failed".

Comment: Let me guess.... on the `Set LookupRange = Range(Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange)` line?  How is the combo-box populated?  What do you have in the `ListFillRange` property?

Comment: Okay i may not have explained properly. The ListFillRange is empty, i don't have an actual list that i'm linking to. Should i use an array instead?